# Trigonometry exercise

Tags: trigonometry

Here's the exercise:

> Let there be a triangle $[PQR]$, with a perimetre of 10 units. Point $R$ belongs to the perpendicular bicector of $[PQ]$. $\cos{R} = \frac{7}{8}$. What is the area of $[PQR]$?

Comment: What is your work on this question ? it is surprising that you haven't recognized that PQR belongs to a  special category of triangles : which one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to notice that $PQR$ is a isocele triangle (that is, $PR$ and $QR$ have the same length).

Let's call $M$ the middle of $PQ$.

Let's call $r$ the semi-angle in $R$.

Then you have the following equations:

$cosR=\frac78=cos{2r}=2cos^2r-1$, that is $cos^2r=\frac{15}{16}$

and $PQ+2PR=10$

and $RM^2+PM^2=PR^2=RM^2+(\frac{PQ}{2})^2$

as well as $RM=PR  \times \cos r$

Then $RM^2=PR^2\times \frac{15}{16}$

Hence $(\frac{PQ}{2})^2=\frac{1}{16}$, or $PQ=\frac12$

Hence $PR=\frac{19}{10}$

The area of $PQR$ is $PM \times RM=\frac14 \times\frac{19}{10} \times \frac{\sqrt15}{4}=\frac{19\sqrt15}{160}$

Comment: I don't agree to help somebody that doesn't want to work by (him/her)self : nothing else than the raw question !

Comment: Well, the question came up this morning, at 8:15, a colleague of mine, presented the exercise. We are going to have a mathematics test at 11:20, I tried to work it out, but, having classes in between, I don't have much time. I thought this would be the best way to figure it out, not being able to do it myself and not having much time to work on it. So, had Martigan not (which I deeply appreciate) helped me, the exercise would remain unsolved for the extent of time in which it would be useful.